# Check input is a valid integer

Tags: c++

Hi Can anyone help me please. I need to check that my input only contains integers. Im guessing from looking it up that I use the `isDigit` function but I am not sure how to use this to check the whole number.

I'm using C++ to interact with MSI so i'm getting the integer as follows:

```
hr = WcaGetProperty(L"LOCKTYPE",&szLockType);
ExitOnFailure(hr, "failed to get the Lock Type");
```

I think i have to change `szLockType` to a char and then use `isdigit` to scan through each character but i am not sure how to implement this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. P.s im a beginner so please excuse if this is a really trivial question..:)

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol will perform the conversion, and throw an exception if it can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the type of szLockType?

Is it a a null-terminated char-string?

Then you can use the array syntax to get individual characters.

```
for(int i = 0; i < std::strlen(szLockType); i++) {
    if(!std::isDigit(szLockType[i])) {
         // it contains a non-digit - do what you have to do and then...
         break; // ...to exit the for-loop
    }
}
```

Or is it a std::string? Then the syntax is slightly different:

```
for(int i = 0; i < szLockType.length(); i++) {
    if(!std::isDigit(szLockType.at(i)) {
         // it contains a non-digit - do what you have to do and then...
         break; // ...to exit the for-loop
    }
}
```

Comment: The value I am getting is a `TCHAR*` will this still work? I tried the first one and even converted it to a char but i wanted a char*.

Comment: Changed it so that is an int..:)

Comment: depending on the plattform, tchar is either a synonym for char (1-byte ASCII-characters) or for wchar (2-byte unicode-characters): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc842072.aspx. The function to get the length of a wchar string is std::wcslen. The wchar version of isdigit is iswdigit.

Comment: Its windows..:) `szLockType` is now an int so il look into converting that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use [std::stoi()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol). You'll get an exception if the string is not an integer value.

Comment: No, it won't check that the input is a valid integer, only that it has a non-whitespace prefix that is a valid integer, e.g: `std::stoi("   123broohaha ")`
will return 123, but `std::stoi("  broohaha123 ")` will throw.

Answer (score 0):

Even better, with modern C++ you can do this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

auto lambda = [](auto elem)
{
    return std::isdigit(elem);
};

return std::all_of(szLockType, szLockType + strlen(szLockType), lambda);
```

Your choice as to whether you prefer a named lambda or regular, anonymous lambda.

FYI it is `std::isdigit` rather than `isDigit`.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit